# Using Javascript to change html visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked through many different Q&A trying to find an answer that I could modify to work for what I am trying to do. What I have is a form which will be used for different "units" within a company that have different requirements for the same form. I am trying to use JS (without using jQuery) to change the visibility of several of the table rows depending on which "unit" number is selected.

Selection box section:

```
<tr>
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Store Number:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="storenumber" name="storenumber" required title="Please select your store ID number" onChange="salad()">
            <option value="">Select Store Number</option>
            <option value="010576">010576</option>
            <option value="011169">011169</option>
            <option value="008181">008181</option>
            <option value="010324">010324</option>
            <option value="008615">008615</option>
            <option value="009150">009150</option>
            <option value="014640">014640</option>
            <option value="010684">010684</option>
            <option value="011168">011168</option>
            <option value="014215">014215</option>
            <option value="008179">008179</option>
            <option value="008339">008339</option>
            <option value="008668">008668</option>
            <option value="031574">031574</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Table rows which should be hidden for some "units":

```
<tr id="frig1" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #1:</td>
    <td><input name="refrig1" type="text" required id="refrig1" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="frig2">
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #2:</td>
    <td><input name="refrig2" type="text" required id="refrig2" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="frig3">
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #3:</td>
    <td><input name="refrig3" type="text" required id="refrig3" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript function I have tried:

```
function salad() {
    var storenumber = document.getElementById("storenumber");
    switch(storenumber.value) {
        case "010576":
            document.getElementById("frig1").style.value = "visible";
            break;
        case "011169":
            break;
        case "008181":
            document.getElementById("frig1").style.value = "visible";
            break;
        case "010324":
        case "008615":
        case "009150":
            break;  
    }
}
```

I have even tried to go to W3Schools to find the answer, however the example they use does not work with my form.

Comment: document.getElementById("frig1").style.visible = "visible" and document.getElementById("frig1").style.visible = "hidden"

Comment: did you try `style.visibility = 'visible'` values would be `'visible'` or `'hidden'`. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp. Note that visibility does not free up the space in the page even when hidden. Use display = 'none' to really free up the visual space.

Comment: Have you tried setting `style.display="none"`? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Comment: Please see the JS code that I have included in the question. If you see I did try `document.getElementById("frig1").style.value = "visible";`

Comment: ... my mistake, I did not see the difference between the `.value` which I was using and the `.visibility` which was being suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the wrong method.

Just try...

```
document.getElementById("frig1").style.visibility = 'visible'
```

This is the syntax for the `visibility` property:

```
visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

do these work?

`document.getElementById("frig1").style.display = 'none'`

and

`document.getElementById("frig1").style.display = 'block'`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
document.getElementById('domElementId').style.visibility = "visible" ;
document.getElementById('domElementId').style.visibility = "hidden" ;
```

Inline style has highest precedence which can create issue in some other case.Rather we can have a class and add it using js

CSS

```
.showMenu{
visibility:visible;
}
.hideMenu{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS changes

```
document.getElementById('domElementId').classList.add("showMenu");
document.getElementById('domElementId').classList.remove("hideMenu");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `document.getElementById(...).style.visibility` and toggle `hidden` vs `visible` not value.  You might mean to use `display: block` and `display: none` as these will remove the row from view completely, while visibility will hide it while maintaining its space on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using
document.getElementById("frig1").style.visibility = "hidden"; -- to hide the element

and 
document.getElementById("frig1").style.visibility = "visible"; -- to make the element visible

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/hLyvhd91/1/

```
var element_to_hide = document.getElementById("row2");

element_to_hide.style.visibility = 'hidden';
//element_to_hide.style.display = 'none';

console.log(element_to_hide.style.visibility);
```