# Using JavaScript to change individule values within an external CSS sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

After combing through many different Q&As I have been unable to find (or at least decode enough to implement in my own code) and answer which will allow me to do what I am needing to do. This question ties into a previous JS question I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644363/using-javascript-to-change-html-visibility). In this previous question I was trying to hid one line of a form table based on which "store number" was selected, there are multiple lines which need to be hidden (or shown respectively) and I am tying to simplify my coding as much as possible using an external CSS style sheet.

**Current HTML**

```
        <tr>
            <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Store Number:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="storenumber" name="storenumber" required title="Please select your store ID number" onChange="salad()">
                    <option value="">Select Store Number</option>
                    <option value="010576">010576</option>
                    <option value="011169">011169</option>
                    <option value="008181">008181</option>
                    <option value="010324">010324</option>
                    <option value="008615">008615</option>
                    <option value="009150">009150</option>
                    <option value="014640">014640</option>
                    <option value="010684">010684</option>
                    <option value="011168">011168</option>
                    <option value="014215">014215</option>
                    <option value="008179">008179</option>
                    <option value="008339">008339</option>
                    <option value="008668">008668</option>
                    <option value="031574">031574</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and

```
        <tr class="hide">
            <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #1:</td>
            <td><input name="refrig1" type="text" required id="refrig1" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
            <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #2:</td>
            <td><input name="refrig2" type="text" required id="refrig2" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
            <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #3:</td>
            <td><input name="refrig3" type="text" required id="refrig3" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
            <td class="noborder"></td>
        </tr>
```

**Current CSS**

```
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

**Attempted JS function**

```
function salad() {
    var storenumber = document.getElementById("storenumber");
    switch(storenumber.value) {
    case "011169":
    case "008181":
        document.getElementsByClassName("hide") = "display: none";
        break;
    case "010576":
    case "010324":
    case "008615":
    case "009150":
    case "014640":
    case "010684":
    case "011168":
    case "014215":
    case "008179":
    case "008339":
    case "008668":
    case "031574":
        document.getElementsByClassName("hide") = "display: show";
        break;  
    }
}
```

I have tried many different variations of the `document.getElements` command but none of them have worked for me

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes. Even if it returned a single node, you couldn't set it to the string `display: show`. Even if you could, the display property has no value `show`.

Comment: You can-not alter the content of a class written in your external `CSS`. Keep the things simple, just switch the `hide` class back n forth.

Comment: @Rohit416: This sounds simple enough however I am not sure how to go about doing this without assigning an id to each element that I want to hide/unhide and then writing a line of code for each element. Could you point me in the right direction as to were to find the answer on how to set this up by class name rather than element id?

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name of the specific element you're trying to access then
you can try...

```
document.getElementByClassName("hidden031574")[0].style.display = "block";
```

Note there is no "show" value in CSS. Also you could use jQuery library.

Or for better implementation.

```
<tr class="010576">
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #1:</td>
    <td><input name="refrig1" type="text" required id="refrig1" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="011169">
    <td class="left"><span class="required">*</span>Refrigeration Unit #2:</td>
    <td><input name="refrig2" type="text" required id="refrig2" size="3" onChange="coldValidate(this)"></td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
</tr>
```

Then the salad function...

```
function salad() {
    var storenumber = document.getElementById("storenumber");
    document.getElementByClassName(storenumber)[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this input however I am trying to stay away from jQuery as this site will be contained within a private and very secure network. I am trying to make everything needed self-contained

Comment: It's okay not to use jQuery library, it's you're preference by the way. But there are too many simple ways to implement this. Just search. Thanks.

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to find elements with a certain class and then add individual style properties. Instead, add or remove classes to and from the elements.